# How do I store data from a stream in Cassandra if I don't know the structure of the data?

Tags: java, cassandra, streaming, cassandra-3.0, key-value-store

I want to know how to apply key-value store using cassandra.
If I have stream of data and I don't know the architecture and structure of it then how to save it using cassandra key-value store and with java code and how is actually work

Answer (score 0):

To use cassandra as a naive key-value store, use a simple schema:

```
CREATE TABLE kvstore (
    key text,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY(key)
)
```

You can use type `blob` instead of type `text` if you know you'll have binary data.

Cassandra's strengths, though, are in clustering. If you consider this very similar schema:

```
CREATE TABLE kvstore (
    key text,
    version int, 
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY(key, version)
)
```

This gives you a very similar key/value store, except all of the `value` s for a given `key` will be sorted naturally by `version` - you can select just a single version (`SELECT * FROM kvstore WHERE key=? AND value=?`) or all of the values for a given key (`SELECT * FROM kvstore WHERE key=?`).